# Unable to get Access Token for Dialogflow REST api

Tags: node.js, google-api, dialogflow-es, google-oauth

There's seems to be about 400 different quickstarts that don't quite solve what I'm looking for, and I find myself going in circles on the google documentation for dialogflow a lot. What I want to be able to do is make a POST request with some text, and get a response with the intents and response from DF. The doc's state that I need my API key, which I already have, and an access token, which I've been unable to pull from the depths of google's servers. Apparently I need to use my client ID (Which I also have) to get my access token, which involves a million different steps of encoding and base64'ing and reencoding again. Even when I managed to do all of that, I only ever got a "bad request" response, with no more information as to how my JWT might've been malformed. I'm banging my head against the desk; I've been at this for nearly a week and I feel as though I am still at square one.

Unfortunately my stack doesn't involve any of the client libraries, but I can make this a bit more complicated by sending a POST to a node.js server, who then sends a POST to google, but even then, that still opened up about 18 more cans of worms. If anyone can walk me through this step by step (with or without the node.js portion), I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Hey @jumpsplat120, I am currently going through those 400 different quickstarts. Google made sure that no-one will be able to use its DialogFlow APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a detect intent request. Based on what you want, you can use curl for which you will need gcloud sdk installed or you can use nodejs (or any other client library).

For both of these ways, you need to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable which should point to the Service Account Key file. The service account should have permission to access dialogflow. You can generate a key for the default dialogflow account that is generated in the IAM.

Node.js Example:
Check this link: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow#using-the-client-library
As mentioned above, set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable before running your code.

curl:
Expand the curl section at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api

Comment: Basically, on both ends, I run into the issue where if I try to use `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`, it tells me that the service token I downloaded has an "Invalid JWT Signature." Any googling I searched for gave me all sorts of unrelated information about forming an JWT

Comment: How did you download the service token?

Comment: I just followed the steps outlined here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/setup#sa-create

Comment: Oh damn, it worked this time! I think maybe it was because I renamed the key file? In any case, I just created a new one and that solved the problem.

Comment: am I supposed to get this working from front end (without having a server at all) I have genrated a servie account key with limited access and it is perfectly okay to expose that token to public, but in every example what I see is server code to get bearer token, what I am looking for is a way to give service account json and get some kind of auth token which i am planing to use to detect intent, please let me know if it is possible, any code example or guide document will be appriciated